# How to Execute Service Fabric Powershell commands from c#?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I used the "System.Management.Automation.dll" for executing PowerShell Commands from C# code. But I could not execute the Service Fabric Commands.

When I execute the Service Fabric commands i get the following error

> The specified module 'ServiceFabric' was not loaded because no valid
>   module file was found in any module directory
>
> The term 'Connect-ServiceFabricCluster' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

The Code I used is

```
 var shell = PowerShell.Create();
 shell.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module ServiceFabric");
 shell.Commands.AddScript("Connect-ServiceFabricCluster");
 var result = shell.Invoke();
```

These Commands worked successfully when I executed them directly from the PowerShell command window.

The above code works fine for other PowerShell Commands

I also tried loading the Module using the physical path 
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ServiceFabric"
That didn't work either.

Comment: Your process have same bitness as OS?

Comment: Changed the Application to 64 bit and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to call powershell commands from C#? All the powershell commands have parity with API - meaning, for each command, there is an API you can use directly. Just create a FabricClient and call whatever methods you need.

Comment: I installed the nuget package for FabricClient, Is there any Documentation for how to use this library? There are references in msdn, but its not upto date.

Comment: After I added the Nuget for FabricCliet. I wrote the following code  System.Fabric.FabricClient client = new System.Fabric.FabricClient("http://localhost:19080");
            var x = await client.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync(); this statement throws an exception {"The supplied address was invalid."} System.Exception {System.Fabric.FabricInvalidAddressException}

Comment: Have you tried using the local FabricClient (do not pass gateway address)? [Local FabricClient overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt161330.aspx).

Comment: I used the FabricClient() overload and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, port 19080 is the HTTP management port. For FabricClient you want the TCP management port, which is typically 19000.