# How to Varify a Service Fabric application package using C# like the powershell command "Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage"?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-service-fabric

I am dynamically creating a service fabric application package using c# , and i need to verify the package using c#.

I could verify the package using PowerShell command "Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage"

Is there a similar method in System.Fabric library for verifying a package ?

Comment: Hai Binu, your question should be more clear to get better response. anyway nice to meet you here, am also from infopark

Comment: The question is that if there is a parity method in c# for "Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage" command. Refer this question please " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526299/how-to-execute-service-fabric-powershell-commands-from-c"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no public managed API that can do this, but you can invoke the PS cmdlet from your C# code using the PowerShell.Invoke pattern.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396